# Printing from a thread in another class with a while loop? ( time inconsistency )

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

Hi I'm trying to code a clock that alternates between 1 and 0 every 500 milliseconds with a thread and print that same thread in another class at it's 500 millisecond sleep rate. I'm a 'thread newbie' and am in need of some help.

### Thread

```
public class clockThread extends Thread {

public void run(){
    chipClass3 chip = new chipClass3();

    int clock = 0;
    while(clock<3){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        clock++;
        clock = clock % 2;

        chip.setClock(clock);
    }
}
```

}

### Other Class

```
    public class chipClass3 {

    private clockThread clck; 
    private int clock = 0 ;

    public chipClass3(){
         clck = new clockThread();
    }

    public static void main(String[]args ){
    chipClass3 chip = new chipClass3();
    new Thread(chip.clck).start();

    chip.printClock();
    }

    private void printClock() {
        while(true){
        System.out.println(getClock());
        }
        }

    public int getClock() {
        return clock;
    }

    public void setClock(int clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }



}
```

Comment: The rule of thumb is: all accesses to a state that is shared between threads must be done in a synchronized way. Your shared state here is the `clock` field. Making it `public` is the biggest error you have, since you can't synchronize access to a public field. Encapsulation is crucial in OO design, and it's even more when dealing with concurrency.

Comment: If you are running tasks at intervals, don't start threads that wait, instead use the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). It will make for better code and 300 milliseconds of sleep is a very long period in computer time.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, as I said I'm a thread newbie and have no idea how synchronized access works. This is my first attempt at using a thread and I'm unsure how to share my threads output with it's wait time. I understand that 300 milliseconds is a lot of wait time. However, I'm using this example to test and understand threads so for testing purposes I would like to have the thread display from the other class at the 300 millisecond wait time in order to understand how to synchronize the output of a thread from a separate class.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you have only one writer to a primitive, if you rewrote to like this

```
clock = 1 - clock;
```

or

```
clock ^= 1;
```

In this situation all you need do is make the field volatile.  If you have multiple writers, or update multiple fields, or non primitive fields, you need to use synchronized or a Lock.

There are other ways to avoid locks, but how you do this is specific to the situation.

In the situation you have, because you update the field twice, you need to use a proper lock or synchronized.

Comment: I disagree. Making the variable volatile won't make `clock++; clock = clock % 2;` atomic as it should be. The reading thread isn't supposed to see 2 ever. Only 0 or 1. It's of course possible to make it thread-safe with volatile only, but the code will have to be changed to only assign the new value once it has been computed.